# Changing a string to have first character uppercase and remainder lowercase

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
var a = "abc";
var b = "DEF";
var c = "gHi";
```

is there a function that I can apply to the string to change it so the first character is an uppercase followed by lowercase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write your own fairly easily.

```
public string Capitalise(string str) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return String.Empty;
    return Char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1).ToLower();
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C#, and this is definitely not C#.

Comment: @MattHamilton - thank you.  I forgot what tag I was in :-O.  I guess it didn't help that he said `var c = "gHi";` :)

Answer (score 8):

`ToTitleCase()` is the ideal solution.  You can find a link to creating an extension method below.  Or for fun you could create one yourself ...

```
public string ToProperCase(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         return str;

    return str[0].ToUpper() + str.Substring(1).ToLower();
}

// or an extension method
public static string ToProperCase(this string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         return str;

    return str[0].ToUpper() + str.Substring(1).ToLower();
}
```

Link to creating `ToTitleCase()` as an extension method on System.String:

http://geekswithblogs.net/mucman/archive/2007/03/26/109892.aspx

Comment: Fix your non-extension-method version and I'll give you an upvote. ;)

Comment: Don't forget the ToUpper on the first character! +1 anyway. It's the most correct answer so far.

Comment: @MattHamilton Good catch again.  I can tell it was late when I was answering this.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase( yourstring);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Title Case... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890/EN-US/